# How to put text after a line beginning with HTTP?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have posts with links and I want to put the word 'HELP' after all URLs starting with `http://`. So, posts with

```
http://google.net
http://yahoo.com
```

will be replaced by

```
http://google.net/HELP
http://yahoo.com/HELP
```

How can I do this with a regex (in Notepad++)?

Comment: Is there other text on the lines after the link?

Answer (score 1):

This should work on Notepad++ (but also elsewhere)

Regex: `(^http://.*)`

Replace with: `$1/HELP`

Comment: this doesnt work. it doesnt add HELP at the end of all lines beginning with http

Comment: I tested it with Notepad++ v6.9.1 and it worked fine. I use the first line in "Find what" and the second in "Replace with", selecting Regular expression in the search mode.

Comment: its not, what is this then: http://imgur.com/a/YNRNi

it doesnt put HELP after each line starting with http:// but putting it to the last line

Comment: It is because you flag the option to use "." to match newlines character too. Remove that flag and it will work.

Comment: it is the ". vindt \n en \r" in your screenshot